# How can I display vertical text in a table with fixed height?

Tags: html, css

I want to display a vertical text on the header of a table; the header has a fixed height. And I want to hidden the overflow too.

My html is:

```
<table border='1px solid black'>
 <thead>
  <tr style='font-weight:bold; color:blue'>
   <td width="60"> Data </td>
   <td width="35"> Voto </td>
   <td width="50"> Tipo </td>
   <td width="10"> I </td>
   <th style="color:red; height:200px; vertical-align:bottom" width="20">
    <span>
      <div style="width:100%;height:100%;overflow:hidden;"> Hi everybody </div>
    </span>
   </th>
   <td> Annotazioni </td>
  </tr>
 </thead>
</table>
```

And my CSS:

```
table
    {
        border-collapse:collapse;
        table-layout: fixed;
        width: 400px;
    }      

th span {

      writing-mode: tb-rl;
      filter: flipv fliph;
      -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg); 
      white-space:nowrap; 
      display:block;
    }
```

I have a problem: it appears only a couple of letters of the vertical text. Why?

Here you can see better: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/m7nfU/21/)

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Did you tried `vertical-align:middle`?

Comment: It doesn't work the same... The text is centered but I continue to see only a couple of letters.

Comment: Always add prefixed properties without prefix too: your example doesn't work in Firefox because of that. Works if you add `transform: rotate(-90deg); ` after the WebKit one. Will also still work when a WebKit browser drops the prefix for this property.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a strange layout for a table, and I'm not sure of the use case. Therefore, I'm not sure how flexible it needs to be, but adding this to `th span` fixes your example:

```
width: 200px;
text-align: center;
margin-left: -90px;
```

Also, add `vertical-align: middle;` to its containing `th`.

http://jsfiddle.net/m7nfU/22/

Comment: **+1** I think this is a better solution =)

Comment: It seems to me it still doesn't work with Chrome. If I want to decrease the height of the header to 100px, I must set height:100px in the th tag and also set width 100px in the CSS. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/m7nfU/25/. And a strange thing happens...

Answer (score 0):

Remove `overflow: hidden` on the div encasing "Hi Everybody" which is hiding the rest of the letters.

```
<th style="color:red; height:200px; vertical-align:bottom" width="20">
     <span>
        <div style="width:100%;height:100%;">Hi everybody</div>
     </span>
</th>
```

Then add, `vertical-align: middle` to the parent `<th>`, I further had to add a negative margin to make "Hi Everybody" to match the centre, as the text string started from the `centre origin`.

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/m7nfU/24/

Comment: I would say the only problem here is that the negative margin you added is based on the length of the text string.

Comment: I modified your suggestion setting height:50 px in th tag and it doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/m7nfU/26/

Comment: What browser are you using? and if the length of the string is longer than the size of the `<td>`, it'll __always__ overflow, despite `overflow:hidden`. If you want your text to be relative to the size of the height of the div, You'll be wanting to use JavaScript.

Comment: Actually it seems possible to hidden text that overflow the dimension of the cell, like in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/m7nfU/27/. But here there are other problems, like you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/m7nfU/25/. PS: I use Chrome

Comment: Hmmm were you able to tweak it to how you wanted it? :x